# Templating ASP.NET MVC4 site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, templates, web-applications

An embedded Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC4 template does not provide neccessary default configuration for a typical web project in our organization. We are usually adding IoC, placing project structure, integrating HTML5 boilerplate, KOJS etc. every time we start a new project.

Currently, to save us time, we have create an "standard" solution with all this initial integration and config, and when we start a new project, we are just renaming namespaces to a new project name and we are off to go.

This is not at all an enterprise approch, or at least it doesn't seem so. How can we improve our approach to this template we use? Would it be better to create a Visual Studio template? I assume many web shops face the same problem and there should be a solid way to approach it.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for T4 templates IIRC. Take a look on msdn and T4MVC to see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, that is an ideea - create a new project template, depends on how often you create projects. Other ideea is to create nuget packages, which could be added to your just created project; the advantage is that these packages can be updated (eg. If you change your boilerplate js files, you can refresh all your current projects with the new version of js files)